# Flex builder 3 word completion/intellisense stopped working?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

Running flex builder 3 on windows 7 RC.

For some reason, my work completion/intellisense stopped working..

If i try to manually trigger the shortcut (alt + /) I hear a windows 'error sound'.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an invalid 'root node' in the xml document.

I discovered this by trying to switch to design mode, noticed the error and just repasted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

at the top. Not sure how it got changed and why the app would still compile/run without errors...